# Windows 10 shortcut Alt+ENTER and Alt+1

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

Since my own Windows 7 machine I was able to use the shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> in my explorer in order to open file or folder attributes (detail window with the file size and other properties).

This also worked a long time on Windows 10 but since a few days after the 1903 update it is no longer functional.
Now I have to use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd>) in order to get the window.

How do I enable <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> again? Was this a Windows built-in feature? Or the shortcut of another program? I am not quite sure, but <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> is so much easier because of the only left hand use.

Comment: the shortcut for properties has always been Alt+Enter. Probably you have some programs or scripts that remap the key https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12445/windows-keyboard-shortcuts

Comment: @phuclv I have Windows 10 1809 and using either ALT+1 or ALT+ENTER both get the properties windows for me. no scripts or anything.

Comment: @Smock I am also quite sure that I never installed a program that would bring this behaviour. But why is it not working anymore? And how to turn it on again?

Comment: Aha! I see that Alt+1, Alt+2, etc. are triggering the items in the Quick Access toolbar in Explorer. Perhaps 1903 removed that toolbar. Or removed or rearranged the items. See if you can find a way to get the toolbar and its items back.

Comment: If you tap 'Alt' when in explorer does it show shortcut keys over all the options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible you've somehow accidentally removed Properties from the Quick Access Toolbar

Should be easy enough to get back again:

[image]

Click the little down arrow to access the Quick Access Toolbar customisation menu:

[image]

to go back to what I believe is the default:

1. Untick all options in this menu
2. Tick 'Properties'
3. Tick 'New Folder'

You should then be able to verify by tapping the Alt button so the shortcut keys appear:

[image]

I've done this using a PC with 1903:

[image]

<sub>shoutout to *Doug Deden* who also realised it was the Quick Access Toolbar</sub>